# Как сделать имитацию страниц в php

Tags: скрипт, php

Доброе утро.

Как сделать что-то вроде пошаговой установки скрипта в DLE? Когда в каждом шаге новая страница. Что это за фишка?

Там копаться долго =)

Нашел, типо того:

```
 if($_REQUEST['action'] == "eula") {
     <input type=hidden name=action value="function_check">
 } elseif($_REQUEST['action'] == "function_check") {
     [next]
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну сделай в скрипте точки по которым нужно пройти скрипту.

- somesait/?install=step1
- somesait/?install=step2
- somesait/?install=step3
- somesait/?install=step4

Ну и в скрипте проверяй, все шаги на правильность заполнения.